# Django: No module named context_processors, Base URL

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-settings, base-url

I've scoured the web for a solution but nothing seems to work. I'm getting the error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /tool/page4/

Error importing module mysite.context_processors: "No module named context_processors"
```

settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
# default context processors for Django 1.4
"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
"django.core.context_processors.media",
"django.core.context_processors.static",
"django.core.context_processors.tz",
"django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
"django.core.context_processors.request",
"mysite.context_processors.baseurl",
)
```

views.py

```
if(team_value != "---------" && product_value != "---------" && type_team.length > 3 && pattern_value.length > 1)
      {
        $.ajax({

              url: {{BASE_URL}}'/tool/page4/add_team/',
              type: 'POST',
              dataType: 'html',
              data: {
                  "team" : team_value,
                  "product" : product_value,
                  "pattern" : pattern_value,
                  "type" : type_team,
                  "array" : data_array
              },
              async: false,

              error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                  alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
              } 
          });
        location.reload(true);
```

Within my project directory, I have my context_processor.py and **init**.py files (both not in a folder), however, it doesn't seem to find those files. If I want to avoid using hard-coded URLs, is this way viable or could someone suggest something otherwise? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what django's version are you using?

Comment: django 1.6.5. It says 1.4 above because I just copied the template context processor from a tutorial

Comment: Do you mean you have `context_processors.py` and not `context_processor.py` and `__init.py__` instead of **init.py**?

Comment: I have both (context processors and __ init __.py) within my project directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The outer project directory is not usually on the Python path. You probably just need `context_processors.base_url`, without the `mysite`.

Comment: Solved it! Thanks everyone for their help.

Answer (score 0):

in my Settings I have:

```
from django.conf import global_settings

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + (
...
'<appname>.context_processors.base_url',
...

)
```