# "No module named context_processors" After Upgrade

Tags: python, django

I've upgraded `Django` from version **1.8** to version **1.10** and I am now getting the below error:

```
No module named context_processors
```

This is in relation to this code in `settings.py`. If I comment out the lines that start with `'django.core` it runs fine but I obviously will be losing functionality:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
        TEMPLATE_PATH,
    ],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'debug': DEBUG,
        'context_processors': [
            ...
            'django.core.context_processors.debug',
            'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
            'django.core.context_processors.media',
            'django.core.context_processors.static',
            'django.core.context_processors.tz',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ...
    ],
    },
},
]
```

How can I fix this?

Note: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32828536/django-no-module-named-context-processors-error-after-reboot), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437055/django-no-module-named-context-processors-base-url) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38772498/importerror-no-module-named-context-processors) are all similar but nothing Google returns addresses this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of digging, I found a fix. Hidden in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.8/#django-core-context-processors) is the solution to the issue:

> django.core.context_processors
>
> Built-in template context processors have been moved to django.template.context_processors.

Hence, in order to fix the issue, you need to replace `django.core` with `django.template`. The code would then look like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
        TEMPLATE_PATH,
    ],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'debug': DEBUG,
        'context_processors': [
            ...
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
            'django.template.context_processors.media',
            'django.template.context_processors.static',
            'django.template.context_processors.tz',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ...
    ],
    },
},
]
```